# How best to implement Google social sign-in authentication in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, google-oauth

I want to implement an authentication system in ASP .NET Core where:

1. The user clicks a button which looks like the standard Google sign-in button.
2. The user is then prompted to sign in to Google Accounts and signs in.
3. A `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` claim with the value equal to that of the `user_id` of the signed-in Google account is added to the `User` variable in the `RazorBasePage` class.
4. The server adds the user to a user table with `user_id` as the primary key.

I originally investigated a solution using the built-in ASP .NET [Identity system.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity) However, I soon realised it was far more functionality than what I needed.

Next, I followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/social-without-identity) to implement a system where the user must authenticate with their Google account when attempting to use controllers or actions tagged with the [Authorize] attribute.

Meanwhile, I also investigated a login system using [this article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) This article implements a system where developer can implement their own custom authorisation system, e.g. check against a hard-coded password.

And I also investigated some of [Google's developer pages on identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) This system allows the developer to easily implement an authentication system on the client side - additional steps are required to pass the authentication to the server.

[This collection of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97oHW.jpg) should help to communicate the aforementioned authorisation systems. My current ConfigureServices method in StartUp.cs contains the following code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogle(options => {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

Any tips on how to implement such a system would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you try to use `ClaimActions`  to get PPI(private personal identifier)?

Comment: No. How do I use that?

Comment: It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2#map-user-data-keys-and-create-claims).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like Google deprecated use of Google+ for retrieving user information:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6486

In ASP.Net Core MVC 2.0 I ended up doing this in Startup.cs:ConfigureServices

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddGoogle(options => {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
                options.ClaimActions.Clear();
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("picture", "picture");
            })
            ;
```

Don't forget to add the following line before app.UseMvc()

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Also, you will need to configure Google API for cloud identity for your app.

To display the information you can do something like:

```
@Context.User.Identity.Name
<img src="@Context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "picture")?.Value" />
```

Finally: Please consider privacy of this information. It's not ethical (and in most jurisdictions not legal) to store private information without telling the user that you are storing it and for what purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Use blow code get user data.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(options => {
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo";
    options.ClaimActions.Clear();   
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.PPID, "ppid");        
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "email");
});
```

This all data you get on your Callback method into controller with in `Claim` `type` and `value`.

If you want to get other into than added your key like `options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes, jsonKey)`